# Replace a double ultegra crankset for a triple ultegra crankset. Is that possible?

Tags: crankset

I would like to exchange a triple Ultegra crankset on one road bicycle to another bicycle with a double Ultegra crankset.

Is that possible?

Comment: You will need to swap front derailleur and shifter in most cases too. I guess the frame might also have compatibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

Most people go the other way. Many new bikes now only come with double chain rings. And compact crank sets give almost the same gear range as triples.

But it should be possible. The distance the front derailleur travels is about the same. You may need to adjust your limit screws though. And of course you need to change the front shifter to a 3 speed version.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but not straightforward.

1. In most cases the bottom bracket is wider on a triple than a double.
2. The front derailleur has a wider range and a different ratio. Note that a standard and compact double ALSO have different derailleurs and you must be cautious since a compact front and a triple front look the same but have different motion ratios.
3. The rear derailleur usually has too small a range and might need to be replaced with a "medium" or "long cage" so that it can absorb the extra chain.
4. The left shifter is probably different for a triple than a double. (There are exceptions)
5. The original chain is no doubt something like 10 links too short.

The bottom line is about the only thing the same in the groups are the brakes.

These are fast rules and there are slight exceptions depending on manufacturers and the exact group you are working with.